# Set the position of the labels inside plotly pie chart

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

i am trying to figure out how to change text position of labels in pie chart or make it more readable (?).
Below is a screenshot of an example and reproducible code:

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(Gruppierung = c("Very long label", "Very very long label", "Long label", "Short label", "Long label / long label"), 
                     freq = c(3.1, 6.2, 8.7, 20, 21))

library(plotly)                                                                                                                                                                       
plot_ly(df, labels=~Gruppierung,values=~freq, marker = list(line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)), type="pie",
        textposition = 'auto',textinfo = 'text',
        hoverinfo = 'text',source = "subset",
        text=~paste(sub(" ","<br>",Gruppierung),":","<br>",paste0(freq,"%") ),
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF')) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE,separators = ',.') %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

My Problem (what i would like to achieve):

**If Label cannot match horizontally the space that it is in, then it should be positioned outside the pie chart**

Thanks for help!

**[!!]** Approach suggested by @Saurabh Chauhan is very good BUT unfortunatelly it would not match every time, here is a screenshot below which could Show the Problem when even with high freq some Labels are not horizontal:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check the `freq`. If `freq` is less than some value for example `less than 5%` then label should positioned outside as follow:

```
plot_ly(df, labels=~Gruppierung,values=~freq, marker = list(line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)), type="pie",
    textposition = ifelse(df$freq<5,"outside","inside"),textinfo = 'text',
    hoverinfo = 'text',source = "subset",
    text=~paste(sub(" ","<br>",Gruppierung),":","<br>",paste0(freq,"%") ),
    insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF')) %>%
    layout(showlegend = FALSE,separators = ',.') %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Screenshot from working demo:

[image]

**Updated**

One more result with (when `freq<10`):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for actually great and simple idea! However this Approach would not always work..see my additional comments

Comment: @Mal_a: I have updated answer. Could please check the updated part? I think this is the problem with your viewer try to open visualization in external windows and you can see the above view. Please feel free to correct me!

Comment: I actually did it in purpose if you mean with the Viewer. Initially my plotly is in shiny app and it takes only small space there....

Comment: @Mal_a: You can increase the space in shiny by increasing using `fixedRow(
         column(10,plotlyOutput("plot"))
    )` so that it can occupy more space. You can increase it to 12 or 15 column (based on your requirement) to occupy more space.

Comment: yeah i know i can increase the space for the pie plot, however intentionally i made it so small, therefore increasing of the space in my case is not possible

Comment: You can also customize the size of your Pi-chart. Ref link: https://plot.ly/r/setting-graph-size/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this thread, here is an updated fix, that works for all pie/plot sizes (tested with plotly v5.8.0):

```
fig = <your_pie_plot>
fig.update_traces(insidetextorientation='horizontal')
fig.show()
```

As long as the textposition is at default or auto, this will position your labels either horizontally inside or outside, if that's not possible.